# How can I have a program that will ask a minimum and maximum number from a user?

Tags: python, methods, module, max, min

How can I have a program that will ask a minimum and maximum number from a user?, Generate a list of 5 random numbers between the minimum and maximum numbers given, and Display another list where the values are square of the generated 5 numbers?

This is my code. I just want it to display each number with its corresponding squared number.

```
from numpy import random
import numpy as np
```

#ask minimun and maximum numbers

```
a=int(input("Minimum Number: "))
b=int(input("Maximum Number: "))
```

#random elements and elements size

```
x=random.randint(a,b , size=(5))
```

#list of 5 random elements

```
print("Generated Numbers:", x)
```

#squared of the 5 random elements

```
print ("Squared Numbers:", np.square(x))
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import random

value1 = int(input("Enter minimum value: "))
value2 = int(input("Enter maximum value: "))

randomValues = []
for i in range(5):
   randomvalue = random.randint(value1,value2)
   randomValues.append(randomvalue)

print("Got Random Values")
print(randomValues)
for value in randomValues:
   squareValue = value*value
   print("Sqare of value: "+str(value)+" is: "+str(squareValue))
```

**Bro/Sis I typed this answer a bit fastly, If u got any syntax error or something else try resolve it**

***EDIT***: *you can skip converting it to int, I thought it is in float type

Comment: Why should the random value be of float type?

Comment: it will not return float it will return int coz it is randint()